# emacs find-tag has trouble with .el.gz files

Tags: emacs, etag

When I use find-tags, I get the following error:

File: /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Contents/Resources/lisp/simple.el not found

simple.el.gz exists and I built TAGS using

```
(find . -name *.el && find . -name *.el.gz) | etags -
```

I'm using the following version of emacs on snow leopard:

"GNU Emacs 23.1.1 (i386-apple-darwin9.7.0, NS apple-appkit-949.46)
 of 2009-07-30 on neutron.local"

Any ideas how to get this to work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have `jka-compr` enabled?  Etags will automatically check for the existence of the compressed versions of files if that is enabled.  This is all you need to add to your .emacs:

```
(require 'jka-compr)
```